# Calculate n % 12

Tags: math, number-theory, atomic-code-golf

Calculate `n` modulo `12` for an unsigned 32 bit integer.

### The Rules:

- Must work for all `n` between 0 and 23. Other numbers optional.
- Must only use any of the operators `+-*`, `~&^|` or `<<`, `>>` as commonly defined on 32 bit uints.
- May use arbitrary number of constant uints.
- May not use any form of pointers, including arrays, or any `if` statements, including things that compile to if statements such as ternary operators or "greater than" operators.

### The scoring:

- Operators `+ -` and the bitwise operators `~ & ^ | << >>` (NOT, AND, XOR, OR, bit shifts) give a score of `1`, `*` gives a score of `2`.
- Lowest total score wins.

Comment: You might want to define the operators for users of languages other than C/Java. I understand `+-*` are add, subtract, multiply; `~&^|` are bitwise NOT,AND,XOR,OR; and `<< >>` are bitshifts.

Comment: @steveverrill - thanks. That is indeed the intention.

Comment: Can I use `for i in x:y:z, .dostuff`?

Comment: Can I set a variable equal to a value to use in a expression?

Comment: @Ourous - not unless you want to count the for increments in the score.

Comment: @xnor - you can use any uint32.

Comment: most compilers will optimize `n % 12` to a multiplication and a shift like in hacker's delight, so this is trivial, just output the assembly and see

Comment: Can I use `-=`?

Comment: Can I use multiple lines and the assignment operator?

Comment: @Ourous I doubt that it helps. `a -= b` can be replaced with `a = a - b` which has no higher a score by the questions scoring system.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021772/assembly-language-how-to-do-modulo Apparently, they just use a builtin.

Comment: @isaacg they'll do it with multiply and shift like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171301/whats-the-fastest-way-to-divide-an-integer-by-3?rq=1), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558492/divide-by-10-using-bit-shifts), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580680/does-a-c-c-compiler-optimize-constant-divisions-by-power-of-two-value-into-shi/2580985#2580985) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113660/divisiblity-of-5-without-using-and-operator?lq=1) instead of simple divisions like that

Comment: Would be better to just say "may not use ternary or comparison operators", rather than assuming that they actually compile to conditional branch instructions in the underlying assembly.

Comment: What if my language uses `*` as the modulo operator?

Comment: This question's score is currently equal to the highest number supported by many answers.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## 4

(Language is irrelevant)

```
n-((48&(11-n))>>2)
```

Woo! Got to 4.

`11-n` will ensure all of the high order bits are set if and only if n>= 12.

`48&(11-n)` == if n>11 then 48 else 0

`(48&(11-n))>>2` == if n>11 then 12 else 0

`n-((48&(11-n))>>2)` is the answer

Comment: Aww shucks, you beat me to this approach! I was only moments away from posting `n - (((11 - n) & 0xC0000000) >> 28)`. Well done, I don't think it can be done in less than four.

Comment: @Runner112 Yeah, I was hoping no one would beat me to it as I posted it. Well done on finding it for yourself, though

Comment: Awesome :) 4 is indeed an accomplishment.

Answer (score 11):

## 4

A solution with a lookup table (it looks up `i ^ (i % 12)`):

```
i ^ (0x1d4c000 >> (i & 0xfc) & 30)
```

## 4

Here's another solution with 4 operations:

```
i - ((0xffff >> (i - 12)) & 12)
```

It assumes that the count operand of bitshifts is implicitly taken mod 32, i.e. `x >> -1` is the same as `x >> 31`.

## 5

Another approach, using a lookup table:

```
i - (16773120 >> i & 1) * 12
```

Answer (score 7):

## bash – 1

```
echo `seq 0 11` `seq 0 11` | awk '{print $(number+1)}'
```

e.g.

```
$ echo `seq 0 11` `seq 0 11` | awk '{print $(0+1)}'
0

$ echo `seq 0 11` `seq 0 11` | awk '{print $(11+1)}'
11

$ echo `seq 0 11` `seq 0 11` | awk '{print $(12+1)}'
0

$ echo `seq 0 11` `seq 0 11` | awk '{print $(23+1)}'
11
```

Comment: This isn't valid because it uses pointers.

Comment: @curiousdannii What pointers are you referring to? The `stdin` and `stdout` streams? Sure, internally, they are pointers, but then we might as well disqualify Java because it uses the `Integer` class internally for a lot of things.

Comment: Isn't $() effectively equivalent to a pointer?

Comment: @curiousdannii - awk documentation says they're built-in variables.

Answer (score 5):

### C, little-endian - 2

This is probably cheating but I think it satisfies the rules...

```
union {
    int i;
    struct {
        int a:4;
        int b:2;
        int c:10;
    } s;
    struct {
        int a:2;
        int b:14;
    } t;
} u;

u.i = 11-n;
u.s.a = 0;
u.s.c = 0;
result = n-u.t.b;
```

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: Sorta cheating, since you're using `= 0 ` instead of `& 0x0`, which should count as an additional 2 operations. But +1 for the creativity :)

Answer (score 4):

## PHP - score 0

I wonder how is it possible that noone came with this before me!!!

```
$n = 18;
$s = str_repeat("a", $n);
$s2 = preg_replace('/aaaaaaaaaaaa/', '', $s);
echo strlen($s2);
```

Comment: Nice. I think there may be an issue though, since arrays are disallowed. Really nice though.

Comment: @AJMansfield One could argue this doesn't have arrays but strings (yes, at low level strings are byte arrays). :)

Comment: @seequ One could also argue that this invalid because of it's use of RAM (yes, at low level, ram is technically an indexed array) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

## C, score 5

Works up to 23, not guaranteed above that.

```
( ((n+4)>>2)&4 ) + n & 15
```

`((n+4)>>2)&4` returns 4 for n>=12. Add it to n and you get the right answer in the least significant 4 bits, then truncate the other bits.

Comment: Well done!! Now let's see if someone can get to 4..

Answer (score 2):

#### whatever language: 5

not going to win, but participating because fun and maybe because it's easier to understand then others:

```
n - ((n+20)>>5)*12
```

this is equivalent to

```
n - (n>11)*12
```

this is equivalent because when you add 20 to 12, you get 32, thus the 5th bit becomes 1. This is only when n > 1 as 32 is the smallest number where the 5th bit becomes 1.

also note that is easily expandable for a higher range, as you can do

```
n - ((n+20)>>5)*12 - ((n+41)>>5)*12
```

to reach a range until 35

Answer (score 1):

## C - 6

```
(n - (((n * 0xAAAB) >> 19)) * 12 )
```

Comment: This should either be part of the question or just another answer. I suggest the latter.

Comment: @Jwosty - changed.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.x - 4

```
j=input();m=lambda a,b:a*b;a=(m(j,357913942)>>32);print j-m(12,a)
```

Is `=` an operator?

In that case the score is 6.

```
j-12*(j*357913942>>32)
```

BTW @steveverrill 's solution can be directly used in Python as well.

Works for the range 0 .. 23

So whats going on ? Multiply by 357913942 and divide by 2^32 (or right shift 32)

Comment: I like how you used a function to multiplicate only once. but imho you just renamed multiplication to the function m(,), which for me means you used it twice.

Comment: depends how the rules are interpreted, but you have a valid point

Answer (score 0):

## [Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona/) - 5

Might be invalid because I'm not sure if the floor operator is allowed, but I've got two `*` and a minus:

```
mod:{x-(_0.08333*x)*12}
```

Which should work for any integer.

Comment: I'm not sure about the floor operation, but I'm definitely sure that the first multiplication is operating on something other than 32-bit integers.

Comment: @Runer112: OP says *input* must be 32 bit and operators are as defined they normally are with 32 bit uints; it says nothing about non-integer values in the code.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, 0.08333*x doesn't seem like multiplication as defined on 32-bit uints, because 0.08333 is not a 32-bit uint.

Comment: @Runer112: Actually, the way I read it is that `&|~ >> <<` are as defined with 32 bit uints (as it doesn't really make sense to do 1.0 << 3, does it?).

Comment: If you have to floor it, I know that, at least in JavaScript, `n|0` is equivalent to a floor function

Comment: "May use arbitrary number of constant uints." - i.e. cannot use arbitrary floats.

Comment: @nbubis: that line does not actually put a restriction on floats.

Answer (score 0):

## Cobra - 2 (or 3)

```cobra
def modulo12(n as uint32) as uint32
        for i in 11:n to int64:12,n-=12
        return n
```

This *might* be bending the rules a bit, but I've asked and was allowed to use this.

It also works for any number.